# Item properties pane serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer issue SPO

Tags: sharepoint-online, serialization

We have done SP2013 to the Online migration for a large custom document library having around 600k items. We are getting the error like "**Properties can not be displayed having error: Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON javaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property**". As per my understanding, It is dependent on the number of columns/content types that the DocumentSet has. The properties pane tries to serialize this in a JSON in order to render the results and it is unable to do it. any help or any lead to resolving it much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Whether you have many lookup columns show in this list which exceed the recommended value?

If true,please refer to Brian Meeuwenberg's reply in [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/properties-do-not-display-due-to-json-javascriptserializer-error/m-p/277072) post, the suggested fix from Microsoft is to reduce the number of lookup columns.